# How to fix "Requested prototype of a value that is not an object" when use react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native

im using react-native and react-native-navigation but when I run the project, occur this error "Requested prototype of a value that is not an object".

i did not to use redux

**App.js :**

```
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import {HomeComponent} from './src/home';


Navigation.registerComponent("navigation.playground.HomeComponent", () => HomeComponent);

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            component: {
                name: 'navigation.playground.HomeComponent'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**index.js :**

```
import {Navigation} from "react-native-navigation";
import {App} from './App';


Navigation.registerComponent(`navigation.playground.HomeComponent`, () => App);

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            component: {
                name: "navigation.playground.HomeComponent"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**home.js :**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';


class HomeComponent extends Component{

    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <Text>This is Home</Text>
            </View>

        );
    }
}


export default HomeComponent;
```

and then end,

**result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this problem when your Gradle is not compatible with your version of react-native
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing

7 and 8 section is very important and the solution of the problem

If you read the documentation carefully, wouldn't happen!

Although the implementation of react-native-navigation is really complicated!

at the end use Gradle 4.4 instead of 4.6 for react-native57

Comment: I am using Gradle 4.4 with react-native57 and still get this error. My gradle properties file includes this- distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Comment: Did you run all the steps of the react native navigation document step by step?

Comment: @mohsen.hI have the same issue and I do every step in Docs !!